# How to add domain to my web app (MVC4) hosted on iis in server 2008?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, dns

I want to add domain to my web app hosted on iis in server 2008 ..
how to add Static IP Address  for server2008  to DNS in Domain ??
I do not know how can add domain to web app ..

Answer (score 0):

First of all to host app on you own server you need an static ip address for you server and then you can add your servers static ip address as a 'A Record' in your domain DNS zone file ,so it will point your domain to your server.
If you add details of your domain registrar details will be better to answer.